# extract last two fields from split

Tags: python

I want to extract last two field values from a variable of varying length. For example, consider the three values below:

```
fe80::e590:1001:7d11:1c7e

ff02::1:ff1f:fb6

fe80::7cbe:e61:f5ab:e62 ff02::1:ff1f:fb6
```

These three lines are of variable lengths. I want to extract only the last two field values if i split each line by delimiter :

That is, from the three lines, i want:

```
7d11, 1c7e

ff1f, fb6

ff1f, fb6
```

Can this be done using `split()`? I am not getting any ideas.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If `s` is the string containing the IPv6 address, use

```
s.split(":")[-2:]
```

to get the last two components.  The `split()` method will return a list of all components, and the `[-2:]` will slice this list to return only the last two elements.

Comment: how can i get the values seperated by :, that is for the first line, how can i get the values like 7d11:1c7e

Comment: seems like some of the delimiters are double `':'`, it would be better to replace all colons to space and use `split()`

Comment: @user1411416 you can use `':'.join()`

Comment: @xvatar: Regarding your first comment, please read about [IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) to see that this proposal doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: If I have a  `var: mango-apple-banana-orange` and if I were to split and combine everything except banana, would that be possible via ansible?
Desired output: `mango-apple-orange` 
`var.split('-')[-2] | join('-')` . I have been trying different ways, cannot seem to tell ansible to ingore the 3rd element. Thoughts pls?

Answer (score 19):

You can use `str.rsplit()` to split from the right:

```
>>> ipaddress = 'fe80::e590:1001:7d11:1c7e'
>>> ipaddress.rsplit(':', 2) # splits at most 2 times from the right
['fe80::e590:1001', '7d11', '1c7e']
```

This avoids the unnecessary splitting of the first part of the address.

Comment: True, but according to my testing, it's only about 6% faster.

Comment: @JoelCornett I think its always good practice to eliminate unnecessary computations no matter how minor.